# Taking screenshot using python

Tags: python, quickly, glade, python-2.7

The below [code](https://askubuntu.com/q/345045/192580) work perfectly when I run it as a console application

```
import gtk.gdk
import time

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])

ts = time.time()
filename = "screenshot"
filename += str(ts)
filename += ".png"

if (pb != None):
    pb.save(filename,"png")
    print "Screenshot saved to "+filename
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

But now I when I used it in a ubuntu application (using the quickly and glade) it is giving me error messages

```
 WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-O1o56xxlHA: Connection refused
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

How can I improve this code to work in GUI based application

**EDIT**
What I have done to change the code

```
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkX11, Gtk

        w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
        geo = w.get_geometry()
        pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,False,8,geo[2],geo[3])
        pb = pb.gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window(w,0,0,geo[2],geo[3])       
        pixbuf = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,geo[2],geo[3])        
        pixbuf.save("xdfgxfdgdfxgfdx.png","png")
        print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
        pix = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window(root_window, 0, 0, 500, 500)
        pix = GdkPixbuf.gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window(window,0,0,500,500);


       ts = time.time()
       filename = "screenshot"
       filename += str(ts)
       filename += ".png"

       if (pix != None):
           pix.save(filename,"png")
           print "Screenshot saved to "+filename
       else:
           print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

But still it is giving me error

```
(0, 0, 1366, 768)
<Pixbuf object at 0x2966410 (GdkPixbuf at 0x2e42d90)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srs/projectob-team/projectob_team/SelectmemoDialog.py", line 63, in on_start_clicked
    pb = pb.gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window(w,0,0,geo[2],geo[3])       
AttributeError: 'Pixbuf' object has no attribute 'gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window'
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to take an Screenshot using PyGobject (the Gtk version used by Quickly) is:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

window = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
x, y, width, height = window.get_geometry()

print("The size of the root window is {} x {}".format(width, height))

# get_from_drawable() was deprecated. See:
# https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7
pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(window, x, y, width, height)

if pb:
    pb.savev("screenshot.png", "png", (), ())
    print("Screenshot saved to screenshot.png.")
else:
    print("Unable to get the screenshot.")
```

The first version you posted is for the older PyGtk. So it works on console because it only loads PyGtk. In Quickly apps, PyGobject is loaded, and you cannot load both. You got stuck looking for get_from_drawable(), see section "GdkDrawable is gone":

https://web.archive.org/web/20140808005032/https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7

Comment: Note the link is 404 (**Not Found**).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix fixed the link. Thanks.